# HashMap with different possible value type

Tags: java

Imagine a situation where you have something like this :

```
class AbstractClass{void sharedMethod()}
class ClassOne extends AbstractClass{void sharedMethod(); void specificMethod()}
class ClassTwo extends AbstractClass{void sharedMethod(); void specificMethod2()}
```

I want to store in a Map something like this :

```
HashMap<String, List<SOMETHING_I_DON'T_KNOW_IN_ADVANCE>> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("blabla", List<ClassOne>);
hm.put("blublu", List<ClassTwo>);
```

I know that I can put AbstractClass as the value type for my map but I want to have access to my specific methods. I already did some research to try to dynamic cast my object when I get them, but I didn't find anything satisfying.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So when you retrieve something, how are you going to know if you can call `specificMethod()` or `specificMethod2()`?

Comment: For example, if I do : hm.get("blabla").get(0) -> I'll know that I'm getting a ClassOne object so I'll know that I have access to specificMethod()

Comment: Sorry, why do you know that "blabla" is ClassOne? Why does a `String` key guarantee a given object?

Comment: Because it's the mapping I decided to do. In practice, the key part corresponds to a type of message and the value part to a list of all the messages of this type. E.g : hm.put(1, List<MessageOfType1>)

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  What if someone passed you an arbitrary `String` and you didn't know what it was?  What kind of `List` would you assign to then?  Why aren't you just writing `class Foo {List<ClassOne> blabla; List<ClassTwo> blublu;} `

Comment: There is a general solution for the problem of needing to store objects of differing types into a map in a type safe way.  This solution is the *"Type Safe Heterogenous Container"*.  Using this pattern enables a more object-oriented approach and avoids much (or all) the ugliness of using instanceof operators (which leads to an ugly and fragile program).  This is a bit of an advanced topic but not too bad, really.  There are many examples online of this pattern in use and there is a whole item devoted to covering it in Effective Java, 2nd Ed. by J. Bloch.

Answer (score 2):

Would creating "abstract void specificMethod()" in your AbstractClass, and then making concrete versions of specificMethod() in your concrete classes work for you?

That way you don't need to worry about whether to call specificMethodOne() or specificMethodTwo() ... the AbstractClass object already knows which version of specificMethod() it's supposed to use.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that I can put AbstractClass as the value type for my map but I want to have access to my specific methods.

I am assuming that you want to do this:

```
List<ClassOne> one = hm.get("blabla");
one.specificMethod();
// or
List<ClassTwo> two = hm.get("blublu");
two.specificMethod2();
```

Unfortunately you can't do this automatically because of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).  The `Map` and `List`s have no idea what types they are storing so there is no way for them to help here.  To them you are storing `Object`s.

Storing different types of objects in a `Collection` is a difficult pattern to support correctly and requires you to do your own casting once you get the values out of the `Map`.

```
List<AbstractClass> list = hm.get("blabla");
if (list instanceof ClassOne) {
    ClassOne one = (ClassOne)list;
    one.specificMethod();
} else if (list instanceof ClassTwo) {
    ClassTwo two = (ClassTwo)list;
    two.specificMethod2();
}
...
```

Yes this is gross and error prone but there is no easy way to do this using Java generics.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider either encapsulating the data in a class, such as

```
private static class MyMessages
{
    final List<ClassOne> typeOneMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<ClassTwo> typeTwoMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTypeOne(ClassOne c) {
        typeOneMessages.add(e);
    }

    // add appropriate getter methods; or a stream
    public Stream<ClassOne> streamOne()
    {
        return typeOneMessages.stream();
    }

    // same for type two
}
```

Or follow what Rick Stabile suggested, and have a single method defined in the abstract class.

If you wish to keep them together, you will have to cast on retrieval, such as:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Map<String, List<? extends AbstractClass>> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<ClassOne> ones = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ones.add(new ClassOne());
    }

    List<ClassTwo> twos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        twos.add(new ClassTwo());
    }

    map.put("ones", ones);
    map.put("twos", twos);

    List<? extends AbstractClass> out = map.get("ones");
    // can call shared method on the contents
    out.stream().forEach(a -> a.sharedMethod());

    // will have to cast to the specific type
    out.stream().filter(a -> a instanceof ClassOne)
        .forEach(c1 -> ((ClassOne)c1).specificMethod());

    List<? extends AbstractClass> out2 = map.get("twos");
    // can call shared method on the contents
    out2.stream().forEach(a -> a.sharedMethod());

    // will have to cast to the specific type 2
    out2.stream().filter(a -> a instanceof ClassTwo)
        .forEach(c2 -> ((ClassTwo)c2).specificMethod2());        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using "wildcard(?) arguments" and because of the "Type Safety" mechanism a cast is inevitable. 
This works for me:

```
    HashMap<String, List<? extends AbstractClass>> hm = new HashMap<>();
    ClassOne class1 = new ClassOne();
    ClassTwo class2 = new ClassTwo();

    List<ClassOne> c1l = new ArrayList<>();
    c1l.add(class1);
    List<ClassTwo> c2l = new ArrayList<>();
    c2l.add(class2);



    hm.put("blabla", c1l);
    hm.put("blublu", c2l);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<ClassOne> xyy = (List<ClassOne>)hm.get("blabla");
    ClassOne c1 = xyy.get(0);
    c1.specificMethod1();
```

and my output was:

```
Hello! from SpecificMethod1
```